# Installing SQL Server 2012 on older instance

Tags: installation, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, multiple-instances

I have SQL Server 2008R2 installed on my server which I can connect either by providing server name "xyz" or IP address "127.xx.xx.xxx". Does it mean my installation is done with default instance?

When I am running below query

```
DECLARE @GetInstances TABLE
    ( Value nvarchar(100),
     InstanceNames nvarchar(100),
     Data nvarchar(100))

Insert into @GetInstances
EXECUTE xp_regread
      @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
      @key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server',
      @value_name = 'InstalledInstances'

Select InstanceNames from @GetInstances
```

and I am getting below result

```
MSSQLSERVER
MSSQLSERVER_2
```

Now, I have to upgrade SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012. As there are many application which is configured with this database (via server name or IP) , so I don't want to change the database server name. In that case do I need to uninstall SQL Server 2008 first or can I install 2012 and then uninstall 2008?

*Eventually, I need to remove SQL Server 2008 from the server*
Please let me know if any more information is required

Comment: You can just do an in-place upgrade and not worry about it...

Comment: @NathanC That seems to be pretty good, thank you ! This means my database, roles and other stuff will automatically be upgraded to SQL Server 2012 ?

Comment: Read the guide on upgrading for anything that might pertain to your environment. Some things *may* require configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can connect to SQL Server with just the server name, then yes, you are running the default instance of SQL Server. If you need to maintain the same instance(server)name then Nathan C is correct, in-place upgrade is probably going to be the best option.

[Supported Version and Edition upgrades TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393.aspx)

Comment: Does that mean that my all databases, their objects (table, view, SP, logins) and server level objects will remain same  ?

Comment: As long as nothing is using a deprecated feature no longer available in 2012